# Huge file to print when using many plots

Tags: r, printing, statistics, knitr, lyx

I am using knitr through Lyx to create a document. In this document, I use knitr to print about 20 images (through R), and 5 calls from R, along with about 20 pages of text.

I save the pdf file, and it is only 1500 KB, and I can view and recompile it easily. But as soon as I go to print, the printer reads about 200MB of information. It takes a super long time (2+ hours) to print.

I was wondering if you knew the solution for this, or even the cause. I’ve been trying to remedy it by just copying the plots and putting them in as figures, but this obviously defeats the purpose of reproducible research. When I put the plots as pictures, we get down to a pdf size of 367 KB. I am fairly certain it is knitr generated plots that are causing the increase in data. When I changed the plots to pictures, it printed in about 5 minutes (which is still a long time, but much shorter than hours).

I've had this issue before, and I believe that it has something to do with plotting of multiple chains for traceplots. Are these known to take forever to print?

Has anyone else experienced this or know the solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for latex output is PDFs for plots. Presumably there are some effects within the PDF which are very expensive to render for your printer. I would specify an alternative graphics device such as `png` either per chunk using chunk options or as default for the whole file using `opts_chunk$set`. The relevant option is `dev` though you may need to change `dpi` too.

[More details on the knitr page](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)

Comment: If you create the plots in an external .R script and then in knitr/latex you read in those portions of the .R script and then have chunka to plot the graphica, does the same slow-down happen?  Second, are you using cache on any one or more of the plots?

Comment: @Nick

I changed the chunk options to that and it printed in about 5 minutes, so it looks like this has solved the problem.

However, do you know of the internals of either Knitr/Lyx/Latex and what causes it to take so long? If I have a normal pdf or image that I want to print it doesn't take nearly as long.

As well, when I save a document as a pdf, is it not already "compiled"?

Comment: @lawyeR I am not sure about the first. I will try that later today.

I have not cached anything.

Comment: @RayVelcoro it's not the latex internals so much as the way the PDF is being rendered for your printer. What type of printer driver is it? I would guess it's Postscript and there's something that is easily represented in PDF but not Postscript. If you wanted to experiment you could try using the `postscript` device directly in R and seeing how the file size compared. You could also use Ghostscript to convert the PDF to PS to look at the resultant file size. Could you add a reproducible example of one of your plots to your question? Or post the PDF somewhere?

Comment: @NickKennedy

The printers are on a network at work. I looked at the drivers, and it is some hp driver.

I can upload a similar document if I can find it. This one has personal information so I can't share it, but I will upload another one that was giving me problems later.

Comment: @RayVelcoro doing some googling there is quite a lot of discussion of slow PDF printing using HP printers. You could try switching between the PCL5, PCL6 and postscript drivers (if your work lets you do so) and see which works best. You could also try updating to a newer driver. You could also try printing from a different PDF reader.

Comment: Here is some latex code for something that uses knitr and prints very slowly.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H33OZqGIX9sYNIOdjROSujpp8iIqUhfccTjOBhxt0is/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's hard to test properly since it's dependent on the program you're using to print PDFs and the specific print driver. But I can see that the plot is made up of 50,000 lines which would go some way to explaining it. The resultant PDF is relatively small (~485 kB) on my machine, but it's slow to open in Adobe Reader. Unless there's good reason, I would suggest for more complex plots like this that you render them as a relatively high resolution PNG rather than as PDF. If you set the resolution high enough, you won't notice any difference on screen or printing.